# Unable to modify ko observable when function defined with object prototype

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I understand it is in general bad practice to modify prototypes with the object.prototype.whatever syntax when using knockout, but I'm trying to understand why this isn't working at all:

```
var Foo = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.bar = ko.observable("bar");
    };
    Foo.prototype.capitalizer = function() {
        self.bar("Bar");
    };
    var vm = function() { 
        var self = this;
        self.whatever = new Foo();
    };
```

js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vvdo7z70/8/

when this works as expected:

```
var Foo = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.bar = ko.observable("bar");
        self.capitalizer = function() {
            self.bar("Bar");
        }
    };
    var vm = function() { 
        var self = this;
        self.whatever = new Foo();
    };
```

js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vvdo7z70/10/

Is it just not possible to pass relevant ko bindings with the object.prototype syntax? or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Pardon the seemingly unnecessary functions but this is inside of a durandal app and the prototype() function just simulates the viewmodel binding.

Answer (score 0):

For one, `self` isn't defined in `Foo.prototype.capitalizer`. Once that's fixed, you need to note that the binding `click: whatever.capitalizer` is using the function, not the method, which is to say, the `whatever` context is not provided. Instead, `vm` is provided as the context. This will work:

```
Foo.prototype.capitalizer = function () {
    this.whatever.bar("Bar");
};
```

or

```
click: whatever.capitalizer.bind(whatever)
```

Comment: The 'self' is a typo- it's 'this' in my actual code.  So as I understand it the Foo.prototype.capitalizer just adds capitalizer as a method and not as a function in the way that explicitly declaring it inside Foo() would?

Comment: No, the problem is how it is called, not how it is declared. When you put `whatever.capitalizer` as the click binding, it is a reference to the `capitalizer` function, which is later invoked without knowing that it came from `whatever`.